# How can i make jQuery(javascript) ajax form data sent less human readable?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Someone using firebug or chrome console could intercept the submitted form data and then switch some of the values, eg.
Sender's ID . I was wondering if I can make data sent  less human readable so the attacker won't want to deal with it.

I saw something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://www.example.com/widget_category.php',
    data: "p=eyJUcmF6ZW5pUG9qYW0iOiIiLCJJREdydXBhIjoiMzA3IiwiSURQb2RHcnVwYSI6MzA3LCJQcm9kYXZhYyI6IiIsIk9rcnV6aSI6W10sIk9wc3RpbmUiOltdLCJDZW5hT2QiOi0xLCJDZW5hRG8iOi0xLCJTdGFuamFQcmVkbWV0YSI6W10sIk5hY2luaVBsYWNhbmphIjpbXSwiRmlsdGVyIjpbXX0=",
    dataType:'html',
    success: function(res){
        $('#limwidget').empty().append(res);
    }
    });
```

Edit: 
I see this question was accepted bad. I just want to point out that i am validating all data received on the server side and  there should be no question about that, but  I just wanted to hide the real sensitive data from database ( and maybe make them also timestamp signed in some manner and different from user to user). 
I realize that  maybe this problem should be considered on server-side(php), that all sensitive data should be swaped on server-side  instead of client-side, so we can avoid security by obscurity.

Thanks for clarifying

One more edit: 
I see now that output from atob function from the example given

```
eyJUcmF6ZW5pUG9qYW0iOiIiLCJJREdydXBhIjoiMzA3IiwiSURQb2RHcnVwYSI6MzA3LCJQcm9kYXZhYyI6IiIsIk9rcnV6aSI6W10sIk9wc3RpbmUiOltdLCJDZW5hT2QiOi0xLCJDZW5hRG8iOi0xLCJTdGFuamFQcmVkbWV0YSI6W10sIk5hY2luaVBsYWNhbmphIjpbXSwiRmlsdGVyIjpbXX0=
```

is

```
{"TrazeniPojam":"","IDGrupa":"307","IDPodGrupa":307,"Prodavac":"","Okruzi":[],"Opstine":[],"CenaOd":-1,"CenaDo":-1,"StanjaPredmeta":[],"NaciniPlacanja":[],"Filter":[]}
```

so I guess that it's useless to start hiding data on client-side.

Comment: if you are creating encryption and description code then you can simply pass data in secured way like human unreadable form

Comment: Don't expose the sensitive data to the front-end in the first place. Only expose encrypted values, then decrypt them on the server side.

Comment: Always write front & backend end code as if the user, or someone malicious can see and modify everything (because they can).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can encode your data to base64 with atob() and btoa(), and then decode it in the server. Be aware that doing this will only obfuscate your code, and won't make it 100% secure.

Here's some info about Base64 encoding for JavaScript.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding

Comment: So you're saying that attackers are unable to call `btoa()` themselves, then re-encrypt with `atob()`?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Less human readable doesn't mean that it can't be read. It's means harder to read. It's obvious that in the frontend anyone good enough will be able to steal your data.

Comment: Someone who is trying to modify the data in the first place would be able to recognise that the data is in Base64 format anyway. Your answer mentions nothing about salting the encryption.

Comment: If it's in the frontend salting the encryption is useless since the attacker would be able to see the salt key. Encoding to B64 only obfuscates the code, I already know that.

Answer (score 1):

They can change anything on the front end even with this change. Everything sent to the client can be read, including any encryption code you use. It is harder potentially but **you are confusing obfuscation for security**.

Obfuscation will not solve the problem.

You should make it your priority to get your server side code to validate and sanitise the data that comes from the front end.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity

Answer (score 1):

You should forget about having sensitive logic on client side and expect to be safe, there is no way to do that.

Even in case you "ofuscate" the output, that evil user could put a breakpoint before the ofuscation and change values at will.

If you concern is that someone could change the `SenderID` then, assuming is valid for your scenario, you could validate on server side that `SenderID` posted is the same that initiated request.

Comment: Nice explanation...+1 for that

Answer (score 0):

Base64, the content will be a bit longer, but widely supported, there're also command line tools to decode it.

Comment: JavaScript has the `atob()` and `btoa()` methods which convert to and from Base64.

Comment: GNU/Linux cmd line tool is `base64` (use `base64 -d` for decoding)

Comment: What I meant was that JavaScript would allow an attacker to decrypt these values right there. Base64 may be less readable, but it certainly isn't a solution to prevent attacks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's safest to just assume that all data from the client is evil and add code on your server to validate and authorize where appropriate. You could encode your data and then decode it on the server, but JavaScript encoding/encryption is less useful than you might want. The attacker could always just open the dev console in the browser, inspect your code, and run whichever encryption method you use on their new malicious data.